# asp mvc: how to render Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostContent) as html in webpage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp mvc website that displays content of posts as plain string! meaning it displays all html tags in the web browser instead of rendering them as html! so If eg I have in my post: `<b>my content </b>` it will show it in the web browser as it is! It won't render those html tags!
In the  view I have:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostContent)
```

and I already tried to use

```
@Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostContent))
```

but that doesn't work and gives errors!
Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

PS: item.PostContent is the content of my post which is being read from my Database which includes html content.

Comment: `@Html.Raw(item.PostContent)`

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem